# Prototypal inheritance in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I'm writing a npm module to reduce the boiler code in my test project and this module will be added as a dev dependency in that test project. I'm using prototype inheritance to extend an existing library(puppeteer). But it seems not to be working. I'm unsure about how and when this module will be loaded?

I have locally installed the module in test project.

Code from local npm module:

```
let {Page}  = require('puppeteer/lib/Page');


Page.prototype.element = async function(selector) {
    return await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});  
}

Page.prototype.sendText = async function(selector, text) {
    let element = await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});
    await element.type(text);
}
```

My test code:

```
jest.setTimeout(60000);
const Browser = require('puppet/factory/BrowserFactory')
require('puppet/puppeteer-extend/Page')

let page;
let browser;

describe('awesome test', () => {
    it('something will be ok', async () => {
      page = await global.__BROWSER__.newPage()
      console.log(await page.hasOwnProperty('sendText'))
      await page.goto('https://google.com')
      await page.sendText('#fakebox-input', "puppeteer")
      await page.screenshot({path: 'google.png', fullPage: true})

      await page.close()
    })
  })
```

> TypeError: page.sendText is not a function

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo

```
Page.prototype.sendTex < --- // here
```

Edit: The easiest way to see if the prototype file is being hit is by logging the prototype immediately afterwards.

```
Page.prototype.sendText = async function(selector, text) {
    let element = await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});
    await element.type(text);
}

console.log(Page.prototype.sendText)
```

Comment: I think that is not the case I changed it deliberately to see if it even loads that module in other test. I have edit the code and problem still exist.

Comment: How do you import your library into the test file?

Comment: at the moment I have it like this `require('puppet/puppeteer-extend/Page')`

Comment: A test you can do is log the method right after you prototype it.

Comment: Prototype inheritance works there seems to be some other problem as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

That's because your function's called `sendTex`.

Change it where you define it:

```
Page.prototype.sendText = async function(selector, text) {
    let element = await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});
    await element.type(text);
}
```

Or where you call it:

```
await page.sendTex('#fakebox-input', "puppeteer")
```

<sub>(Don't do both)</sub>